# c# Asp.net Error :Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is a portion of a code ..

```
public Admin_GetCourseById_spResult GetCourseById(long? courseId, short languageId)
    {
        ISQUserDataContext db = CreateDataContext();
        Admin_GetCourseById_spResult result;
        result = db.Admin_GetCourseById_sp(courseId,false,languageId).FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
```

the third line in the function throws error `Specified cast is not valid.`
Any clue about whats happening ??

Comment: Isn't `Admin_GetCourseById_sp` returning a `Course`? because it looks like it by the name. or a CourseRow which you need to parse as Course?

Comment: What returns `Admin_GetCourseById_sp`?

Comment: Probably the stored procedure has been changed meanwhile and an output column contains data of another type

Comment: What is the return type for the stored procedure? You can use SQL Cast inside your stored procedure for the correct data type.

Comment: @AdrianIftode thnks dat was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Small rewrite (needs more work)

```
public Course GetCourseById(long? courseId, short languageId)
{
    ISQUserDataContext db = CreateDataContext();
    return new Course(db.Admin_GetCourseById_sp(courseId, false, languageId).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

and then add a class `Course` with a constructor accepting the returntype of `Admin_GetCourseById_sp` to build a nice `Course` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your 
db.Admin_GetCourseById_sp(courseId,false,languageId).FirstOrDefault() line returns a datarow.
(It might return null if there are no data)

Therefore what you can do is this,

you can set each attribute of your

Admin_GetCourseById_spResult result object with the matching value from the returned datarow

i.e result.courseId = row["course_id"].ToString()

{ I assumed that courseId is String in your Admin_GetCourseById_spResult class + the matching db column is course_id.

You have given little data, so could answer only like this. Good Luck !